# Change the email address drupal sends to when a user signs up for my site

Tags: emails

I have a Drupal website, and it sends me emails when someone signs up for my site, but I want to change the email address that drupal sends me emails to because I don't check that email often enough. I keep finding how to change the from address, but not how to change where drupal emails me to.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Rules to send out this email? If so, the email address is in your rule configuration.

Comment: The main address that Drupal uses for sending e-mails is at admin/config/system/site-information
Configuration -> Site Information This is _The From address in automated e-mails sent during registration and new password requests, and other notifications._